# Testing two algebras for isomorphism

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, algorithms

Given two finite dimensional algebras over a finite field. What is the fastest algorithm to check wheter they are isomorphic ? As far as I know there is no such algorithm yet in GAP, which might indicate that there is no good solution to this problem yet.
If it helps we can assume that the algebras are quiver algebras. Is there an argument that it is more or less impossible to reduce the problem to a linear algebra problem?

Comment: Magma has an " IsIsomorphic" function for basic algebras, but I've not tried using it. https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/978#11083

Comment: The problem is, generally, difficult and is, of course, not linear. There are some approaches using Groebner bases and randomized algorithms, but in general there is no "good solution".